# ASP.NET MVC RC ajax onsubmit

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

The problem with onsubmit still continues when I even use preventDefault option. My problem is the same with [Asp.net mvc beta ajax problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237691/aspnet-mvc-beta-ajax-upgrade-problem)

```
<% using (this.Ajax.BeginForm("den2",
                              "Deneme",
                              null,
                              new AjaxOptions {
                                   UpdateTargetId = "panel1",
                                   InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace
                              },
                              new { id = "panelOneForm" })) { }  %>
<div class="panel" id="panel1">
   <img src="/Content/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $get("panelOneForm").onsubmit({ preventDefault: function() { } });
</script>
```

This time I get the following error:

```
e.type is undefined
var etype = this.type = e.type.toLowerCase();
```

When I debug it :

```
 var e = Function._validateParams(arguments, [

 {name: "eventObject"} ]);

 if (e) throw e;

 var e = eventObject;

 var etype = this.type = e.type.toLowerCase();

 this.rawEvent = e;

 ...(function continues) at MicrosoftAjax.debug.js line 2862
```

Is there a way to solve it or should I pass each parameter property used in this method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I found that was an issue with the RC version of MicrosoftAjax.js

It works fine if I use an older version of this file. Not a solution, but it will help temporarly.